# javax.mail unable to send attachment without setting content

Tags: java, email, spring-boot, smtp

i have a class which uses javax.mail.* to send multipart emails. when i try to send file with setting `content` is throws a `FileNotFoundException`. how ever, when is use `attachmentBodyPart.setContent(...)` it sends the email but replaces content of the file(kind of corrupts file other then text files). i also tried `attachmentBodyPart.attachFile(...)` i also throws same exception as before even after giving absolute path of the file. below is my class -

```
//all import statements
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

@Component
@Service
public class Notifier {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Notifier.class);

@Override
public ResponseEntity<Object> sendEmail(InternetAddress[] to, 
                                        InternetAddress from, 
                                        InternetAddress[] cc,
                                        String subject, 
                                        String body, 
                                        File attachment) {

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    //setting all the required properties
    LOG.info("SMTP properties set!");

    try
    {                
           Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
           Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
           message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mail_from));
           message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
           message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, cc);

           if(subject.isEmpty() || subject.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            subject="No Subject";
           }
           message.setSubject(subject);

           message.setHeader("X-Priority", "1");


           Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
           //set attachment
           if(attachment != null){
               MimeBodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
               DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachment);
               attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

               attachmentBodyPart.setFileName(attachment.getName());
               attachmentBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/plain;charset=utf-8");
               //attachmentBodyPart.attachFile(attachment);
               //create a mime body part for containing body
               MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
               messageBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html;charset=utf-8");

               multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
               multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);


               LOG.info("Attachment and Body added to mail");
               message.setContent(multipart);
           }
           Transport.send(message);
           return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    } catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();return null}
```

My Exception without `setContent(...)` method

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1652)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:961)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:553)
at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:81)
at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)
at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1652)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1850)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1259)
[wrapped] javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message; nested exception is: java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt (The system cannot find the file specified) at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1308) at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:255) at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124) at test.project.notification.service.impl.notifier.sendEmail(Notifier.java:73) at test.project.rest.RestClass.receive(RestClass.java:50) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your exception: it seems like the file you are sending to notifier is not available. Check with the calling method.

Comment: Thank you soo much :) the problem was with the calling method. It was unable to parse file.